# Optional argument after subparsers in argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I have code:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--verbose', action='count', default=0, help='debug output')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(help='subparser')
parser1 = subparsers.add_parser('action', help='Do something')
parser1.add_argument('--start', action='store_true', help='start')
parser1.add_argument('--stop', action='store_true', help='stop')
parser2 = subparsers.add_parser('control', help='Control something')
parser2.add_argument('--input', action='store_true', help='start')
parser2.add_argument('--output', action='store_true', help='stop')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Then I can run script:

> script.py --verbose action --start
>
> script.py --verbose control --output

but not

> script.py action --start --verbose
>
> script.py control --output --verbose

Can I transfer option --verbose to the end, without adding it to each group?

Comment: Did you consider using a wrapper library such as [argh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argh)?

Comment: I would give a definitive `no` except I can't run tests or examine the code from this tablet -well I guess I could with `qpython` but would be a pain to type it all in.  The explanation lies in how parsing is handed off to the subparser.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment:

`argparse` parses the input list (sys.argv[1:]) in order, matching the strings with the Actions (`add_argument` object).  So if the command is

```
 python foo.py --arg1=3 cmd --arg2=4
```

it tries to handle '--arg1', then 'cmd'.  If 'cmd' matches a subparser name, it then delegates the parsing to that parser, giving the remaining strings to it.  If the `cmd` subparser can handle `--arg2`, it returns that as an `unrecognized` argument.

The main parser does not resume parsing.  Rather it just handles the `unrecognized` arguments as it normally would - raising an error if using `parse_args`, and returning them in the `extras` list if using `parse_known_args`.

So if you want to put `--verbose` at the end, you have define it as a subparser argument.  Or do some further parsing after `parse_known_args`.

You are allowed to define `--verbose` at both levels, though sometimes such a definition can create conflicts (especially if defaults differ).

The `parents` mechanism can be used to reduce the amount of typing, though you could just as easily write your own utility functions.